# Fluid Sim: unable to achieve constant stream

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm currently working on a coffee machine and wanted to take the chance and dive deeper in fluid simulations.
I now tried every parameter for days, but I only get results that look like some gnome is filling your coffee cup with an high pressure cleaner. (left) What I want is a nice, small, constant stream of coffee as illustrated on the right.
The only thing that got me closer was cranking up the viscosity, but when it reaches the cup it looks like it's filling with black ketchup.
Very grateful for every hint that might help!

Thanks,
Julius

[image: Fig. 1]

[image: Fig. 2]

Comment: maybe this tutorial can help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B0QM4Cft5c

Comment: do you have flip fluids or would you use it if it works for you? i can offer a solution with flip fluids and playing around with the settings for some minutes i got this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVKPi.gif and no...i couldn't make it with mantaflow with which i tried 20 mins...without sucess

Comment: although i got nothing for my advertising for flip fluids here *sigh* it is pretty amazing. Much faster than mantaflow...and (!) you can keep on working while it it baking!! And inbuild are some materials two....like ocean water...and coffee ;)

Comment: @NatureK yeah I've seen that one, my problem with this is that it is too much fluid and I couldn't reduce the amount. It looks more like something being poured out a bottle.

Comment: @Chris Hm that looks pretty promising! Yeah maybe I should take a look at this one. Even if I'm switching to blender because it's free... :D Tbh, for 76$ you could buy Maya or 3ds Max for like two days, so probably I shouldn't care.

Comment: Or you wait. They make regular cheaper offers. I bought it for 52€ I think…